# MySQL: Replication without MySQL table, add user to replicated database on slave

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MySQL master / slave setup.
Only one database is replicated.  (not mysql)
So now i cannot add users on the replicated database on the slave.

> `#1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'bladiebla'`

Since root on the slave does not have root on the database?
Also tried adding a user on the master on that particular database, but that will not help since the mysql table is not replicated.

How can I add a user on the database on the slave?

Comment: The message you're getting has nothign whatsoever to do with replication but with how mysql authentication works; random users from random remote systems can't simply access and update the remote database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this on slave

> GRANT ALL ON bladiebla.* to root@'%'

If it will not work, show output from

> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%';